# Kotlin: setting custom labels on x axis in line chart Mpandroidchart

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

i have an arrayList of String with lots of dates (4500 app), i need put all this dates on the xAxis of my chart create with MPAndroidChart, how can do this i Kotlin?

Here is my code:

```
 val chart= ChartUtils()
    val mChart:LineChart = root.findViewById(R.id.lineChartEvolCuota) as LineChart

    mChart.isDragEnabled = true
    mChart.setScaleEnabled(false)
    mChart.axisRight.isEnabled=false
    val test : MutableList<object> = db.Object()
    val yArray= ArrayList<Entry>()
    val xLabel  = ArrayList<String>()

    var c = 0f
    for (i in test){
        yArray.add(Entry(c, i.value!!.toFloat()))
        xLabel.add(i.date.toString())
        c+=1f
    }

    val xaxis:XAxis = mChart.xAxis
    xaxis.granularity=1f

    val set1 = LineDataSet(yFondoA, "TEST")
    set1 .color = Color.parseColor(color)
    set1 .setDrawCircles(false)
    set1 .setDrawValues(false)
    val data = LineData(set1)
    mChart.data = data
    mChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(365f)
    mChart.moveViewToX(c)
```

[image]

**SOLUTION**

```
 val xaxis:XAxis = mChart.xAxis
    xaxis.granularity=1f
    xaxis.setValueFormatter(object : ValueFormatter() {
        val pattern = "dd MMM yy"
        private val mFormat = SimpleDateFormat(pattern)
        private val inputFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
        override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float): String {
            val millis = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(value.toLong())
            return mFormat.format(inputFormat.parse(xLabel[value.toInt()]))
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a nice java example [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/main/java/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/LineChartTime.java) that I think will help you:

```
xAxis.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {

            private final SimpleDateFormat mFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);

            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value) {

                long millis = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis((long) value);
                return mFormat.format(new Date(millis));
            }
        });
```

When copying the java segment to your code, your jetbrains IDE will ask you to automatically convert to kotlin.

Using a custom formatter is cleaner than manually setting the labels.
Depending on how your dates are extracted from the data you will possibly need to adjust the following line from the example:

```
long millis = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis((long) value);
```

Also note that you added your labels to a list but never use them afterwards, which is why you are not seeing them.